# Not splitting the sentence.

Tags: php

I'm trying to split the data I retrieve from the server database. The code goes like this.

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","admin");//username password changed

mysql_select_db("ensig");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT field_id_1 FROM exp_channel_data") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["video_path"] = array();

    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $s1 = explode('"',$row1[field_id_1]);
    echo $s1;
    }
}
?>
```

The feild_id_1 contains video frame paths like iframe which contain src and path of video from which I have to extract the path like http://www.youtube.com/embed/xA-M3kEpGt0. The above code only displaying "Array". I don't know why it is showing so. Please help me on this. I'm newbie to php.

Comment: `explode` return you an array, use `print_r($s1)` to check what you have got.

Answer (score 3):

**Change**

```
$s1 = explode('"',$row1[field_id_1]);
```

**to**

```
$s1 = explode('"',$row1['field_id_1']);
```

and `explode` will give to `array` which contains element which are `separated` by `separator` that you have specified in `explode` as **first argument**.

so use `print_r()` to see result.

**Complete code would be**

```
<?php

    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","admin");

    mysql_select_db("ensig");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT field_id_1 FROM exp_channel_data") or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $response["video_path"] = array();
        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $s1 = explode('"',$row1['field_id_1']);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($s1);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    }
?>
```